# Do physicians who also have an MBA or PhD provide better care?

Tags: research

I see an increasing amount of physicians that have some MBA or PhD in addition to their medical diploma. Is there any study/survey that looked at whether physicians with MBA or PhD provide more accurate diagnosis, more successful treatment, or other improvement to standard medical care?

Comment: When you say "better care" do you mean " are they nicer?" I would guess not necessarily. Simply because people are different and you can have nicer people that don't have advanced degrees and not such nice people that do have advanced degrees. Degrees don't say much about the character of a person

Comment: @larry909 sorry I meant better medical care, i.e. more accurate diagnosis, treatment, etc.

Comment: I'm curious as to whether you're including rejection of CAM in your "better Care" qualification.

Comment: I can imagine narrow circumstances where a PhD might improve care but an MBA? No, they don't teach anything of use to patients in an MBA program. Frankly, it's usually rather the contrary.